# Python - Detect input within a terminal screensaver

Tags: python, curses, screensaver

I'm writing a code that basically runs without a loop for the sake of mobility and functionality. Let's say that when I run the program I use the -i option to continue using the python interpreter as it loads every function written. The thing is that I'm using a screensaver like function after the program print some basic information to make it look not so boring.

My question is: How can I maintain the screen saver running without blocking the interpreter prompt. I already wrote how to handle keyboard input to stop it using curses "getch()". I tried using threading but with no avail as it doesn't detect any keyboard input so it keeps running.

Is there any way I can get around this? How can I detect any input without blocking therefore retaining the interpreter prompt?

Right know it detects an input and raise a KeyboardException captured to make the screensaver stop.

Thanks in advance

I'm using this code with some added modifications:
[Matrix-Curses](http://github.com/devsnd/matrix-curses/)

What I have so far:
[Completed Code](https://codepad.co/snippet/Y55Krhgk)

This are the modifications done to the code:

```
def clear(int=None):
   """ Clear Terminal Screen """

   from subprocess import call  
   call('clear')
   if int == 0:
      exit()

def Matrix():
   steps = 0
   global scr
   curses.curs_set(0)
   curses.noecho()

   if USE_COLORS:
      curses.start_color()
      curses.use_default_colors()
      curses.init_pair(COLOR_CHAR_NORMAL, curses.COLOR_GREEN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
      curses.init_pair(COLOR_CHAR_HIGHLIGHT, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_GREEN)
      curses.init_pair(COLOR_WINDOW, curses.COLOR_GREEN, curses.COLOR_GREEN)

   height, width = scr.getmaxyx()    
   window_animation = None
   lines = []
   for i in range(DROPPING_CHARS):
       l = FallingChar(width, MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED)
       l.y = randint(0, height-2)
       lines.append(l)

   scr.refresh()
   while True:
      height, width = scr.getmaxyx()
      for line in lines:
         line.tick(scr, steps)
      for i in range(RANDOM_CLEANUP):
          x = randint(0, width-1)
          y = randint(0, height-1)
          scr.addstr(y, x, ' ')
      if randint(0, WINDOW_CHANCE) == 1:
         if window_animation is None:
            #start window animation
            line = random.choice(lines)
            window_animation = WindowAnimation(line.x, line.y)
      if not window_animation is None:
         still_active = window_animation.tick(scr, steps)
         if not still_active:
            window_animation = None

      scr.refresh()
      time.sleep(SLEEP_MILLIS)
      if SCREENSAVER_MODE:
         key_pressed = scr.getch() != -1
         if key_pressed:
            raise KeyboardInterrupt

      steps += 1

def ScreenSaver():

   from time import sleep
   from datetime import datetime as dt

   global scr

   TimeLimit = 10
   StartTime = dt.now()

   while True:
      try:
         sleep(1)
         StopTime = (dt.now() - StartTime)
         LastTime = StopTime.days*86400000 + StopTime.seconds*1000 + StopTime.microseconds/1000

         if LastTime >= TimeLimit:
            GetLocaleStatus = locale.getlocale()
            locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
            scr = curses.initscr()
            scr.nodelay(1)

            key_being_pressed = scr.getch() != -1
            if not key_being_pressed:
               try:
                  Matrix()
               except KeyboardInterrupt:  
                  TimeLimit = 30000  
                  StartTime = dt.now()

                  raise KeyboardInterrupt 

      except KeyboardInterrupt:
         curses.endwin()
         curses.curs_set(1)
         curses.reset_shell_mode()
         curses.echo()
         clear()

         # return
         main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by **curses "getch()"**? Please show us a bit of the code you wrote so far. Otherwise this is not clear enough.

Comment: @AbdelhakimAkodadi check my edit and thanks